# How are options added to Windows explorer context menus using C or C++?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

For instance, when I right-click in an explorer window I see a popup with the following:

- Open
- Open with
- Copy
- Paste
- Winrar <-- How can I add a choice like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381811/add-item-to-right-click-menu

Comment: yes  but i want it in core C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Shell Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468984%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

For simple actions you can add some registry settings using the method of your choice ([c# example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx) but the method is simple and agnostic).

For more complex stuff [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx).

Comment: thanks Alex! for "The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions."
very helpful!!!

Answer (score 2):

The codeproject article is good. if you prefer a more solid reference, a friend of mine ( Scott Seely ) wrote a book called "Windows Shell Programming" that covers this ( in C++ ) very well. I'm not sure about posting URLs to store sites, so I'll just give the isbn for the book.

ISBN: 0130254967